# How to read a NCZ file into R?

Tags: r

I have a `.ncz` file that contains some geospatial data that I need to retrieve data from. As far as I know, `.ncz` files are suitable for a specific geospatial program known as Netcad, however I need to open this file in R as I do not have a membership for Netcad program. I really could not find anyway to conduct this operation and although I know that this question is very ambivalent and not specific, I do appreciate any help and tips to be able to open this file in R. Thank you for your attention beforehand.

Note: based on one of the comments I tried the following code to read the data into R;

```
library(ncdf4)
nc <- nc_open("~/data.NCZ")
```

however, it gave the following error:

```
 Error in R_nc4_open: NetCDF: Unknown file format Error in nc_open("~/data.NCZ") : Error in nc_open trying to open file ~/data.NCZ (return_on_error= FALSE )
```

Comment: My guess is that it's a proprietary format, either private or just nobody has bothered to implement a binary reader for other programs. I don't have NetCAD installed so can only guess.

Comment: There's [`ncdf4`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ncdf4/index.html) package around. Try it, good luck!

Comment: I am still getting an unknown file format error. FYI I tried the following basic code: library(ncdf4)
nc <- nc_open(~/data.ncz")

Comment: Probably a Netcad version mismatch, but don't see your error message. Edit your question with what you came forward and show output.

Comment: Here is the code and the error: nc <- nc_open("~/data.NCZ")
Error in R_nc4_open: NetCDF: Unknown file format
Error in nc_open("~/data.NCZ") : 
  Error in nc_open trying to open file ~/data.NCZ (return_on_error= FALSE )

Comment: Suggesting to contact the author, find in my ink above.

Comment: NCZ is a CAD format specific to the NetCAD software. It has nothing to do with the NetCDF format so `ncdf4` or `RNetCDF` won't read these files.

Comment: Okay but do you have any suggestion to read such a file in R?